# Processing list of events efficiently

Tags: java

I have a list of events

```
List<Event> events;
```

Each event has an action and time when this action should be activated. This list is sorted, but time gaps between consecutive events might be large or small.

I thoght about having a separate thread with while loop, but it isn't efficient as time gaps might be large. One improvement might be something like that :

1. check first element
2. if date is ok

   2.1 process event

   2.2 remove event from list
3. if date isn't ok

   3.1 calculate diff = event_time - actual_time

   3.2 go sleep for diff time

   3.3 go to 1.

Could it be done better ?_

My question isn't running a specific method on a given time. Those events should be processed exactly in the same order as they are in the events list. Two consecutive events might have the same time.

Comment: use scheduler, your approach is not that good

Comment: read above question and its answers specially quartz-schedulers are good in my opinion

Comment: I thought about TimerTask, but how can I be sure that if two tasks have the same time, they'll be processed in the order from the given list ?

Comment: @Leosu You'd have to provide all the events with the same time to the same task, presumably in the order you want them processed

Comment: but the problem is that I don't have the whole list ( or different more efficient data structure ) in advance. I am receiving those events

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

To schedule a task after a delay use:

```
schedule(Runnable command, long delay, TimeUnit unit)
```

Here is the JavaDoc: [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)

Here are some examples: [Examples](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/scheduledthreadpoolexecutor/java-util-concurrent-scheduledthreadpoolexecutor-example/)